# DbContext disposed after send a mail with SmtpClient

Tags: entity-framework, autofac, smtpclient

Im trying to send a mail async with a litte logging in the database when smtpclient fails send. I'm using WebAPI 2.2 + EF6 + Autofac. The error says:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

My main code:

```
public class SMTPEmailSender : IEmailSender
{
     [...]
public void SendMailAsync(string templateKey, object model, string subject, MailAddress fromAddress, List<MailAddress> toAddresses,
        List<MailAddress> ccAddresses = null, List<MailAddress> replyTo = null)
    {
        try
        {
            var htmlBody = GenerateHtmlBody(templateKey, model);

            var client = new SmtpClient();

            var message = new MailMessage
            {
                From = fromAddress,
                Subject = subject,
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                Body = htmlBody
            };

            toAddresses.ForEach(m => message.To.Add(m));
            if (ccAddresses != null) ccAddresses.ForEach(m => message.CC.Add(m));
            if (replyTo != null) replyTo.ForEach(m => message.ReplyToList.Add(m));
            client.SendCompleted += SendCompletedCallback;
            client.SendAsync(message, message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: " + ex.Message + "<br/><br/>Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException);
        }
    }

private void SendCompletedCallback(object s, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        SmtpClient callbackClient = s as SmtpClient;
        MailMessage callbackMailMessage = e.UserState as MailMessage;

        var regData = SenderMailLogModel(callbackMailMessage);

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            try
            {
                callbackClient.Send(callbackMailMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                regData.EmailSenderStatus = EmailSenderStatuses.Cancelled;
                regData.Exception = ex.Message;
            }

        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            regData.EmailSenderStatus = EmailSenderStatuses.Error;
            regData.Exception = e.Error.ToString() + " in SendCompletedHandlerEvent";
        }

        _dbContext.EmailSenderLogs.Add(regData);  //here fails

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();

        callbackClient.Dispose();
        callbackMailMessage.Dispose();
    }
    [...]
}
```

My DataContext is injected by Autofac. My container builder configuration:

```
[...]
containerBuilder.RegisterType<DbEntities>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
containerBuilder.RegisterType<SMTPEmailSender>().As<IEmailSender>().InstancePerRequest();
[...]
```

I have a hacky solution for this, you can create a new DbEntities object and use it instead of autofac injected object.

Comment: This is happening because you are using `InstancePerRequest`. This will dispose of the `DbContext` when `Application_EndRequest` is happens with the `HttpContext`, which occurs *before* your mail is sent. You need some kind of hybrid scope for your `DbEntities` lifetime. Not sure if AutoFac offers this, but SimpleInjector does. http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html

Comment: Autofac offers hybrid lifetimes. I don't know well how works lifetime scopes and disposal. I just were looking to migrate my projects to simpleinjector, it appears to be simpler and faster.

Comment: SimpleInjector is a pleasure to work with IMO, it is a great IoC tool.

Comment: Although I'm not sure it is appropriate to advice the OP to switch tools here, I do agree with @danludwig about Simple Injector :-)

Comment: @Steven I was not trying to advise switching ioc's if it came across that way. Just trying to help point out the issue.

Comment: The issue has been resolved, but not directly. I just switched ioc container to simple injector due to a issue with the autofac container configuration and hangfire. It ioc was easy to configure lifetime scopes and the operation took few time to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steven is brilliant, but I have to say I think async email message delivery can be OK. I believe the problem can be solved with the addition of one or two more interfaces. This solution is more complex and Steven's is a lot simpler, but I'll offer it anyway:

```
public interface IDeliverEmailMessage
{
    void Deliver(int emailMessageId);
}

public interface IDeliverMailMessage
{
    void Deliver(MailMessage mailMessage,
        SendCompletedEventHandler sendCompleted = null,
        object userState = null);
}

public interface IDeliveredEmailMessage
{
    void OnDelivered(int emailMessageId, Exception error, bool cancelled);
}
```

The naming convention here is that `Email` means an email message according to your application, whereas `Mail` means an email message according to the low-level System.Net.Mail transports. In this case I assume you store the (Email) messages in a database separately from their physical network (Mail) transportation.

The first interface is consumed by your application like your web project, and you can pass it whatever data it needs to initiate the sending of the email:

```
public class ActiveEmailMessageDelivery : IDeliverEmailMessage
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _entities;
    private readonly IDeliverMailMessage _mail;
    private readonly IDeliveredEmailMessage _email;

    public ActiveEmailMessageDelivery(MyDbContext entities,
        IDeliverMailMessage mail, IDeliveredEmailMessage email)
    {
        _entities = entities;
        _mail = mail;
        _email = email;
    }

    public void Deliver(int emailMessageId)
    {
        var entity = _entities.Set<EmailMessage>()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.EmailAddress)
            .Single(x => x.Id == emailMessageId)
        ;

        // don't send the message if it has already been sent
        if (entity.SentOnUtc.HasValue) return;

        // don't send the message if it is not supposed to be sent yet
        if (entity.SendOnUtc > DateTime.UtcNow) return;

        var from = new MailAddress(entity.From);
        var to = new MailAddress(entity.EmailAddress.Value);
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to)
        {
            Subject = entity.Subject,
            Body = entity.Body,
            IsBodyHtml = entity.IsBodyHtml,
        };

        var sendState = new SendEmailMessageState
        {
            EmailMessageId = emailMessageId,
        };
        _mail.Deliver(mailMessage, OnSendCompleted, sendState);
    }

    private class SendEmailMessageState
    {
        public int EmailMessageId { get; set; }
    }

    private void OnSendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var state = (SendEmailMessageState) e.UserState;
        _email.OnDelivered(state.EmailMessageId, e.Error, e.Cancelled);
    }
}
```

The second interface opens the transport to submit the message:

```
public class SmtpMailMessageDelivery : IDeliverMailMessage, IDisposable
{
    public SmtpMailMessageDelivery()
    {
        SmtpClientInstance = new SmtpClient();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SmtpClientInstance.Dispose();
    }

    protected SmtpClient SmtpClientInstance { get; private set; }

    public virtual void Deliver(MailMessage message,
        SendCompletedEventHandler sendCompleted = null,
        object userState = null)
    {
        if (sendCompleted != null)
            SmtpClientInstance.SendCompleted += sendCompleted;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            SmtpClientInstance.SendAsync(message, userState));
    }
}
```

...and the third will do anything you need to post-delivery, way after the web request has completed and a result has been returned to the user:

```
public class OnEmailMessageDelivery : IDeliveredEmailMessage
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _entities;

    public OnEmailMessageDelivery(MyDbContext entities)
    {
        _entities = entities;
    }

    public void OnDelivered(int emailMessageId, Exception error, bool cancelled)
    {
        var entity = _entities.Find<EmailMessage>(emailMessageId);
        entity.LastSendError = error != null ? error.Message : null;
        entity.CancelledOnUtc = cancelled
            ? DateTime.UtcNow : (DateTime?)null;

        if (error == null && !cancelled)
            entity.SentOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The DbContext instance in the 3rd interface implementation would be resolved outside of a web request, and would get a custom lifetime scope. A reference implementation of this can be found in [the Tripod project](https://github.com/danludwig/tripod/tree/master/Tripod.Services/Net).

Comment: Thanks danludwig! Your help have been very useful. I've adapted your solution to my project and configured container lifetime checking your tripod code (I just switched this project to simple injector yesterday). All is working flawlessly. I will check your tripod project, it's very interesting in my first look.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it is a good idea at all to send this mail asynchronously. You probably started making this method asynchronous, because of performance problems in your web requests. But since sending mail could take some time, the `SendCompleted` callback overlaps the lifespan of your web request. Since Autofac is in control of the components it creates, it will also dispose them when their lifetime ends. For a `DbContext` this will usually mean that it is disposed when the web request ends.

Although sending the mail asynchronously, wouldn't be that big of a deal, you have an extra requirement in doing 'some stuff' when the operation completed, making your current approach unsuited.

Instead, a much simpler approach is to use the `SmtpClient` in a synchronous fashion, but offload the `SMTPEmailSender` to a background thread. This way you can start a custom lifetime scope and resolve the mail sender within that scope. You can put this infrastructure logic (the creation of the lifetime scope) inside a proxy that you place in your composition root.

I'm not exactly sure how to do this with Autofac, but with Simple Injector it will look as follows:

```cs
public class AsyncSmtpEmailSenderProxy : IEmailSender
{
    private readonly Container container;
    public AsyncSmtpEmailSenderProxy(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void void SendMail(string templateKey, object model, ...) {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            try {
                using (container.BeginLifetimeScope()) {
                    var sender = container.GetInstance<SMTPEmailSender>();
                    sender.SendMail(templateKey, model, ...);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Log exception here. Don't let it bubble up: that would
                // end the application.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can implement your `SMTPEmailSender` in a synchronous fashion, which is much easier, cleaner and more maintainable. And just by adding the proxy we make the real sender behave asynchronous.

This can be registered as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingle<IEmailSender, AsyncSmtpEmailSenderProxy>();
container.Register<IEmailSender, SMTPEmailSender>();
```

Comment: Autofac version would look almost identical, save a few identifier name changes. Container would be ILifetimeScope and GetInstance would be Resolve.

Comment: @JimBolla: Feel free to update my answer with the Autofac registration.

Comment: @JimBolla: Or feel free of course to add your own answer with the Autofac equivalent of the registrations presented here. You'll have my upvote for that.

Comment: I think your answer is close enough that op should be able to figure out what he needs to change.